# How to DeserializeObject Using JsonExtensionData, SerializeObject using JsonProperty

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a class named BuildRaw, it has a data source that contains json data whose schema is partly not certain, like

```
{
  "event_type": "123",
  "a": "a",
  "b": "b"
}
```

or

```
{
  "event_type": "123",
  "c": "c",
  "d": "d"
}
```

I want to map the no matching class member into a specified collection ("CustomDimensions" as shown below) when deserialize, and write values in this collection in a specific JsonProperty ("customDimensions" as shown below) when serialize. Its ouput is expected to be like

```
{
  "event_type": "123",
  "customDimensions":{
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b"
  }
}, and 
{
  "event_type": "123",
  "customDimensions":{
    "c": "c",
    "d": "d"
  }
}
```

I try to place these attributes together like below(is it support to place two attributes?),

```
[JsonProperty("customDimensions")]
[JsonExtensionData]
```

but it seems that only JsonExtensionData work. It can successfully deserialize but when serialize it outputs:

```
{
  "event_type": "123",
  "a": "a",
  "b": "b"
}
```

, not as I expected, like

```
{
  "event_type": "123",
  "customDimensions":{
    "a": "a",
    "b": "b"
  }
}
```

my class code now:

```
public class BuildRaw
{
    [JsonProperty("customDimensions")]
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public IDictionary<string, object> CustomDimensions { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("event_type")]
    public string EventType { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you might need to have two properties - one for receiving the extension data, and one for exporting the CustomDimensions object you want:

```
private IDictionary<string, object> _customDimensions;

[JsonExtensionData(WriteData = false)]
public IDictionary<string, object> ExtensionData
{
    get { return _customDimensions; }
    set { _customDimensions = value; }
}

[JsonProperty("customDimensions")]
public IDictionary<string, object> CustomDimensions
{
    get { return _customDimensions; }
    set { _customDimensions = value; }
}
```

So what we have here:

- A common backing field for both properties.
- We're pasing `WriteData = false` to `JsonExtensionDataAttribute`, so this should serve to only READ and not WRITE the extra values.
- A property through which we can serialize (and of course deserialize) the `CustomDimensions` property.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/HWXP92806)

Alternatively, you could write a `JsonConverter`, although I think that would be more complicated.

Comment: Good advice, but one more question, can we pase something like `ReadData = false` to `[JsonProperty("customDimensions")]`, so this should serve to only WRITE and not read the values?

Comment: @czh I believe that to be the case, yes.

Comment: I mean that are there some methods to make [JsonProperty("customDimensions")] serve to only wirte and not read? Just in case that there may be the exact property named "customDimensions" in my data.

Comment: You mean a completely unrelated property? It sounds like you might be better off with two completely separate classes, one for reading and one for writing. You have to understand that your use case isn't a common one so there isn't much stuff built in to handle it.